# stop chronometer with a condition

Tags: android

Now I am working on a Android application.In my application I have to use a Chronometer to show a timer.I started timer using the following code.

```
chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chrono.start();
```

Now I want to call stop method when a particular time exceeds.
Please help me to solve this issue friends.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. it worked for me. set chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener and in that put a condition where you get the time from chronometer as a text and then do whatever you want.

```
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String currentTime= chrono.getText().toString();
    if(currentTime.equals("03:00")) //put time according to you
    {
      chrono.stop();
     }
    }
});
```

the OnChronometerTickListener method gets called every time the chronometer has incremented.

Comment: this line if(currenttime.equals("03:00"))
the variable currenttime is typed wrong currenTime.

Answer (score 2):

Check like this :

```
if(currentTime.equals("3:00")){
    chrono.stop();
}
```

In this case you have you own time line limits say i compared with String "3:00" , you can have your conditions as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`if (condition)` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

save the initial time before starting your chronometer..

```
starttime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chrono.start();

 timeelapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
if(timeelapsed-starttime<5000){timeelapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();}
  chrono.stop();
```

Comment: :O.. why will it not stop??there is method stop for chronometer .. right?