# how to stop chronometer after particular time.?

Tags: android

```
    cmtr.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    timetest = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.d("SETTIME: ", ""+timetest);
    cmtr.start();

    eltime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.d("ELapsed: ", ""+eltime);
    if(eltime - timetest < 5000)
        cmtr.stop();
```

Note: I want to stop my chronometer time after particular time elapsed. like after 10 second i want to stop chronometer. how its possible. anyone knows.? so please any one help me. i didnt fine any help from internet. and i am very new in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stop chronometer with a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005959/stop-chronometer-with-a-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the `Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener` and look at the elapsed time inside this method.

Other than that you could also use the `CountDownTimer` class as well.

For at simple example on how to use it, take a look at this tutorial: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/24/simple-countdown-timer-in-android/

It's really easy to implement.

Answer (score 7):

Use Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() here is the code

```
final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.chronometer1);

    myChronometer.start();
    myChronometer
            .setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                    if( chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:50"))
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "time reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```